# lookup a name and then pull the closest previous date associated with that name

Tags: excel

Would someone help me with an excel formula with my example below? 
I have two tabs in excel: tab 1 lists a bunch of names and admission dates; tab 2 lists names and transfer dates. I would like to pull the closest previous admission date to the specific person's transfer date into tab 2.
Specific Example:

**Tab 1**

```
Names     :       Admission Date;

Able,Bob :         8/1/17;

Barry,Cathy :     10/1/17;

Able,Bob  :         5/1/17;

Barry, Cathy :      6/1/17;

Able,Bob   :        11/1/17;
```

**Tab 2**

```
Names :          Transfer Date;          

Able,Bob  :        6/30/17;

Barry, Cathy :     7/12/17;

Able,Bob    :      12/1/17;
```

**I would like Tab 2 to show the below:**

```
Names   :        Transfer Date  ,    **Admission Date;

Able,Bob  :        6/30/17   ,         **5/1/17;

Barry, Cathy  :    7/12/17   ,         **6/1/17;

Able,Bob  :        12/1/17   ,        **11/1/17;
```

Please assume that each name and date are in its own cell in excel. Example in tab 1 the first "Able,Bob" is in cell A2, "8/1/17" is in cell B2, the first "Barry, Cathy" in cell A3, etc.

**I would like to pull the closest previous admission date to the specific person's transfer date.

Could anyone help me with this? I have tried several MAX, VLOOKUP, and LOOKUP formulas.

Thank you!

Comment: Barry, Cathy is one person. The full name would be Cathy Barry.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is the `A` and `B` columns that are populated in each sheet and labels in Row1 (no gaps), please try in C2 in Tab 2 and copied down to suit:

```
=MAX(IF(('Tab 1'!A:A=A2)*('Tab 1'!B:B<B2),'Tab 1'!B:B))
```

with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>